# object HTMLcollection[0] keeps returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose we have something like:

```
<a href="1" class="my-list">1</a>
<a href="2" class="my-list">2</a>
<a href="3" class="my-list">3</a>
```

When I try something like

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName("my-list"))
```

I get `object HTMLCollection`. And if I try something like `alert(document.getElementsByClassName("my-list")[0])` I get `undefined`. How can I get the first `href` in the list? So it would be `"1"` in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this in [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/mwpmk9kk/9/). Place the `document.getElementsByClassName("my-list")` in a round bracket and the add the index [0] to it.

```js
**UPDATE**: Use `window.onload` to perform operations after all DOM elements 
are loaded.


window.onload = function()
{ 
   alert((document.getElementsByClassName("my-list"))[0])
}
```

```html
<a href="http//:www.google.com/" class="my-list">1</a>
<a href="http//:www.facebook.com/" class="my-list">2</a>
<a href="http//:www.sample.com/" class="my-list">3</a>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I won't always know the values "1", "2", or "3". They can really be anything, but I'm just trying to return the first one (which is "1" in this example).

Comment: @Bob John : [1] is not value, it specifies the index.

Comment: If you need to get the first value, then specify the index as [0].

Comment: Have you run the 'Run Code snippet' in the answer?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work on the site I'm trying it on. I suspect it's because the elements need to load before I try to call this. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Is it possible to do this without having the button you press on? For example, when I run it in fiddle I want it to just alert the first result without me having to click anything.

Comment: @Bob John:Call the load() on <body> onLoad event. check this. http://jsfiddle.net/mwpmk9kk/11/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70839/discussion-between-kumar-and-bob-john).

Comment: @Bob John:It will be achived using jquery. check this http://jsfiddle.net/mwpmk9kk/14/

Answer (score 3):

It could happen if you add the script in the HTML header. In this case, you saw `HTMLCollection`; however, the items would be empty.

move the script to the bottom of the HTML body.

Answer (score 1):

Also, just be sure to check your code, I had this problem from using querySelector. If you use querySelector it only returns one element (which will return undefined when iterating), while querySelectorAll creates a html collection which you can iterate through.